# How to get all Uses who is register in parse.. using PFInstallation in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, parse-platform

I am using below code to fetch users but I am not able to get it.. app is crashes... Please help me to get all installation objects list..

```
PFQuery *userQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"_Installation"];
[userQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        // The find succeeded.
        NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved %d scores.", objects.count);
        NSLog(@"objc...%@",objects);
        // Do something with the found objects
        for (PFObject *object in objects) {
            NSLog(@"id...%@",object.objectId);
        }
    } else {
        // Log details of the failure
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }
}];
```

Comment: What is the crash? Why are you using the private class name? All your code does is to log things. Installations aren't users...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
PFQuery *userQuery = [PFInstallation query];
[userQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        // The find succeeded.
        NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved %d scores.", objects.count);
        NSLog(@"objc...%@",objects);
        // Do something with the found objects
        for (PFObject *object in objects) {
            NSLog(@"id...%@",object.objectId);
        }
    } else {
        // Log details of the failure
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }
}];
```

FYI, Wain is correct in his comment that installations are not users. Are you sure this is the class you want to query?

Comment: it is giving  error as below:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Cannot directly query the Installation class.'

Answer (score 1):

With Parse, as flexible and sound it is, they are limitations to it. Some are extremely worrying in my opinion as a developer that uses Parse, and some are just implemented server side to protect your end-users. This is one, you can not query the Installation class from a client, the only columns you can query are listed in the [API Reference](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFInstallation.html#//api/name/query) . However, you *can* query the class through a cloud function using the master key, otherwise, you will have to use a pointer/relation to other tables for whatever data you want to retrieve. Additionally, for future question seekers, please refer to Wains note. It's a valid statement and should be considered prior to proceeding with anything. Users are not installations, the same 'user' i.e., device, can re-download the app multiple times creating numerous installations (not users).